# Query select report data from databse where hour

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am have problem with query select mysql, I have table :

[image]

that data I save to table, now i want get data like image.

[image]

I hope everybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Well the resulting table is tricky to get, this would be a complete other question on how to format it this way. 
But about how to get the data actually (see [MySQL description of time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(TIME(ts)) FROM table
```

This will give you `10;11` as result.
But you might want a distinct combination of ts and log so

```
SELECT DISTINCT HOUR(TIME(ts)), log FROM table
```

The result will be:

```
10 | a
10 | b
10 | c
....
11 | a
11 | b
```

Now lets go and count how many occurences have been found, so we don'T select distinct anymore but group by hour and log:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIME(ts)) AS h, log As l, COUNT(log) FROM table GROUP BY HOUR(TIME(ts)), log
```

Answer (score 0):

try follow query:

```
SELECT distinct log ,HOUR(ts) as h,(select count(id) from table_t e2 where e2.log=e.log) as data   

FROM table_t as e order by h;
```

and use loop in your code to reprsent data in table